# How to set a default registry to pull from in docker machine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-registry

I have docker machine and by default it pulls my images from docker hub.
Now we have our own repo which can serve as a remote proxy to docker hub.
We can pull with `docker pull server/repo/image`.

Now I want that `docker pull image` resolves to our registry instead of docker hub. How can I achieve this in docker machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the default docker registry is not possible. You can only configure a private registry to act as a mirror for the dockerhub registry as documented in [Registry as a pull through cache](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/).

Check [moby-33069](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33069) issue which has requested this feature.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done if you're using the Red Hat fork of Docker which is in their repo's, CentOS or EPEL not sure.
You use the --add-repository flag.
If I'm not mistaken you can also change the default repo if you build from source.